# android- viewpager setCurrentItem make first fragment not loaded

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i'm using viewpager and `FragmentPagerAdapter` in my application . in the first activity , this is my code :

```
      viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout.setScrollPosition(2,0f,true);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("id",id);

    Fragment_contacts contact=new Fragment_contacts();
    contact.setArguments(bundle);

    Fragment_info info=new Fragment_info();
    info.setArguments(bundle);

    Fragment_Menu menu=new Fragment_Menu() ;
    menu.setArguments(bundle);

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(contact, "تماس با ما");
    adapter.addFragment(info, "درباره ما");
    adapter.addFragment(menu, "منو");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

I'm using `setCurrentItem` because my application is no in english and the default selected tab should be on the right .

When I use `setCurrentItem`  , the `Fragment_contacts` is not loading and it's not showing any thing , but when I remove `setCurrentItem` , it loads perfectly.

what is the problem ? how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ViewPager` will take some time at initialization before you could use `setCurrentItem`. So set it after the intialization of your ViewPager by calling it in a thread, like this:

```
viewPager.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping reference to your fragment in your activity, try to do the same in your `ViewPager`

The view pager is probably already initialized when you add your item in the list and there is a kind of "synchronization" issue between the two.

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager, Bundle bundle) {
        super(manager);
        Fragment_contacts contact=new Fragment_contacts();
        contact.setArguments(bundle);

        Fragment_info info=new Fragment_info();
        info.setArguments(bundle);

        Fragment_Menu menu=new Fragment_Menu() ;
        menu.setArguments(bundle);

        adapter.addFragment(contact, "تماس با ما");
        adapter.addFragment(info, "درباره ما");
        adapter.addFragment(menu, "منو");
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
 }
```